# foreach $_POST as $value create

Tags: php, foreach, http-post

I just started learning PHP and I am having some difficulties with some of the coding. 
Hopefully, someone could help me a little.

I'm using this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['yyy'])) {
    foreach($_POST['yyy'] as $a1) {
echo " $a1";}}
```

The echo will write several results of `$a1` depending on how many were selected in the form.
What I want is to save those results to some values so I can add them in MySQL.

Something like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['yyy'])) 
{
    foreach($_POST['yyy'] as $a1) 
{
echo " $a1";  where $a1 will create a $result1,$result2,$result3(for each isset)
}
}
```

Then if I use:

```
echo "$result2";
```

it will give me the second result.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear whether you are asking about this kind of result or not. But you can use an array to store each values inside the foreach loop.

```
var data=[];// define an array to access outside of if statement later..
if(!empty($_POST['yyy'])) {
    foreach($_POST['yyy'] as $a1){
     data[]=$a1;
    //or can use array_push() method 
    array_push(data,$a1);
    }
}
/*this will give the second result(because array indexing starts from 0. So to get third result 
use data[2])*/

echo data[1];
```

Furthermore by echoing quoted variable will not give the value of that variable but gives a string literal.

```
echo "$result2"  //output---> $result
```